# How can I validate a C++ object's state upon access without duplication

Tags: c++, software-design

I have a C++ object running in a separate thread, with its state being updated in an asynchronous manner. The code resembles the following:

```
class Controller : public Listener {
public:
    // Controller methods, to be called by the user from the main thread
    // My problem is that I am obliged to duplicate the call to validateState() in all methods
    void doAction1() {
        validateState(); // explicit call to validate state
    }
    void doAction2() {
        validateState(); // explicit call to validate state duplicated here and in every doActionX() method. 
    }
    ...

private:
    // Override Listener virtual methods(which are used as callbacks), called in an async manner
    void onXYZ() override;
    void onError(std::string) override { /* update m_error */ }
    ...

    // validate that no error has occurred
    void validateState() { 
        if(m_error) throw m_error;
    }

private:
    Error m_error; // updated 
};
```

I thought of a solution, to overload `operator->` and call `validateState()` once inside, and thus removing the duplicated calls. However, the problem is that the user must do `controller->doAction1()` and be prohibited from doing `controller.doAction1()`.

I can also think of other semantic issues with this approach:

- One would expect overloading `operator->` would be done for memory management issues (such as having a custom allocator), and not just any random operation.
- the lack of symmetry between `->` and `.`

Is duplicating the call for `validateState()` on newly added methods OK here? The intent being to avoid over-engineered designs.

What would be a plausible approach/design here?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "duplicate" call? Show usage.

Comment: The intention is that an `Error` is always thrown on the main thread? And the `Error` is constructed on an arbitrary thread? Note that you will need to synchronise access to `m_error`, the easiest way would to be if it were a `std::atomic<Error>`

Comment: @Caleth For the error logic you mentioned, this is exactly the case. I agree that the access to Error should be synchronized, however, I didn't put the code here since my question was about validating the state really. If you find the code should be further corrected, don't hesitate to edit.

Comment: @iammilind I further clarified the code to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine for all the public functions of a class to call the same private function. Your function is just making sure the implicit `this` parameter is valid, which is the same as any other parameter validation

```
void Controller::doAction1(Arg1 arg1)
{
    // ensure preconditions hold
    validateState();
    validateArg1(arg1);

    // "real" code
}

void Controller::doAction2(Arg2 arg2, Arg3 arg3)
{
    // ensure preconditions hold
    validateState();
    validateArg2(arg2);
    validateArg3(arg3);

    // "real" code
}
```